# Importing packages in flutter using dart

Tags: flutter, dart, import

for other packages like the flutter package we use the following import:

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

but why are we doing this for dart packages?

`import 'dart:io';`

why can't it be same like flutter?:

`import 'package:dart/io/platform.dart';`

Comment: The packages imported with `dart:` are thee built-in packages that are part of the Dart SDK.  They are not necessarily implemented as Dart code.

Comment: What do you mean by `They are not necessarily implemented as Dart code`?

Comment: Much of the Dart SDK is implemented in C++ (for native) or in JavaScript (for web).

Answer (score 0):

The `package:` prefix is used to import libraries found in packages while the `dart:` prefix is used to import the core libraries (such as `io`, `collection`, `convert`...).

Consequently, we don't use the `package` prefix for the core libraries because they're already built-in and no need to add them to the pubspec file.